# How to cancel Kingfisher image downloading previous request when new request occured in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimageview, kingfisher

How can I cancel the previous request if any new request has occur. I am using one image view in which 2 images will be downloading from two different URLs. If I had raise request for first image, and immediately for the second, then first image get downloaded, But I want second should download.

For Image Download, I am using below code...

```
ImageCache.default.retrieveImage(forKey: cacheName, options: nil){
                    image, cacheType in
                    if image == nil {
                            var downloadedImage: UIImage?
                            ImageDownloader.default.downloadImage(with: imgURL, options: [], progressBlock: nil) {
                                (image, error, url, data) in
                                if let downloadedImg = image {
                                    downloadedImage = downloadedImg
                                    self.saveImageInCache(objImage: downloadedImg, cacheName: cacheName)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        loaderVw.isHidden = true
                        self.image = image
                    }
                }
```

I have used below code, but it is not working.

```
kf.cancelDownloadTask()
```

Note: I am playing with multiple images on button click, Image View should show the image which we will get from last action.

Comment: Showing the code on how you are getting the images would be very useful. Basically any code related to the process you are attempting to get working would be useful.

Comment: Please check the updated code